# Unit impulse response of a discrete-time LTI system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, signal-processing, z-transform

The problem:

> Consider a discrete-time LTI system. If the output signal is:
>   $$ y[n]=5 \left( \frac{1}{5} \right) ^n u[n] -2^{-n} u[n]  $$
>   , then the input signal will be:
>   $$ x[n]=\left( \frac{4}{5} \right) ^n u[n]  $$
>   Find the transfer function and the unit impulse response.

We first find the z-transforms:
$$ Y(z)= 5\left( \frac{5z}{5z-1} \right) -\frac{2z}{2z-1}  $$
$$ \Rightarrow Y(z)= \frac{z(40z-23) }{(5z-1)(2z-1)}   $$
$$ X(z)= \frac{\frac{5z}{4}}{\frac{5z}{4}-1}= \frac{5z}{5z-4}  $$
$$ H(z)=\frac{Y(z)}{X(z)}=
\frac{(5z-4)(40z-23)}{5(5z-1)(2z-1)}=4-\frac{15}{5z-1}+\frac{3}{5(2z-1)} $$

Now, [WolframAlpha says](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4%2B15m%2F(m-5)+%2B+(3%2F5)m%2F(2-m)) that:
$$ 4-\frac{15}{5z-1}+\frac{3}{5(2z-1)}=\frac{92}{5}+ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}
\left( \frac{3\cdot 2^{-n}}{5}- 3\cdot 5^{1-n} \right) z^{-n}  $$

If you see any mistakes, please do let me know. Now, I need to find the unit impulse response $h[n] $. The inverse $z-$transform
of the infinite sum is trivial (I think), but I do not know how can I get rid of $\frac{92}{5}$ .

Is there any other way to find $h[n] $ ?

Comment: Why not simply invert $H(z)$ directly? You know how to invert 1 and $\frac{1}{z-u}$ I guess?

Comment: @Paul , thanks for the comment. I was using a table that does not include $\frac{1}{z-u}$ . I found another table that is more comprehensive: http://control.dii.unisi.it/sdc/altro/TabellaTrasformataZ.pdf  . However, the first answer below, from LutzL, has been the most insightful part for me regarding this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the system is LTI, the response to
$$
\tilde x[n]=\left(\frac45\right)^nu[n-1]=\frac45\left(\frac45\right)^{n-1}u[n-1]
$$
is
$$
\tilde y[n]=\frac45\left(5\left(\frac15\right)^{n-1}u[n-1]-2^{1-n}u[n-1]\right)
$$
so that the answer to the unit pulse $x-\tilde x$ is
$$
h[n]=y[n]-\tilde y[n]=5\left(\frac15\right)^n(u[n]-4u[n-1])-2^{-n}\left(u[n]-\frac85u[n-1]\right)
$$
Now use that $u[n]=u[n-1]+\delta[n]$ to simplify to
$$
h[n]=\underbrace{\left(20-\frac85\right)}_{=\frac{92}5}δ[n]- 15\left(\frac15\right)^n u[n]+\frac35\cdot 2^{-n} u[n] 
$$
which is exactly what you got, so it is highly probable that also your intermediate steps were correct.